# Android GCM repeating notifications

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the cordova plugin for GCM at [GCM-Cordova](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova). On the server side, I am using [ToothlessGear's node module](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm).

I think I am not going to use a 'collapsible' key as I require a payload to be sent to the client. The problem I am facing is that the message keeps on arriving after an interval of about 30 seconds. Why is the google server not realizing that the message has been received? Do I have to explicitly do something to stop repeating notifications?

The node-gcm code for triggering push :

```
gcm = require('node-gcm');

message = new gcm.Message();

sender = new gcm.Sender(app.settings.gcm.server_key);

registrationId = [];

registrationId.push(regid);

message.addData('title', 'Payment Request');

message.addData('message', JSON.stringify(someObj));

message.delayWhileIdle = true;

message.timeToLive = 3;

sender.send(message, registrationId, 1, function(result) {
  return console.log(result);
});
```